# Display text box in another page after checking a checkbox,

Tags: php

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Document Title</TITLE>

<script>
function c(){}


function test(){
if(document["f1"]["chkGuar"].checked){
document.getElementById("myrow").style.visibility="visible"
}
else{
document.getElementById("myrow").style.visibility="hidden"
}
}

</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<FORM NAME="f1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkGuar" value="ON" onclick = "c() ; test()">
<div id="myrow" style="visibility:hidden">
<input type = text name ='txtGRTNo' tabindex = 19 size="20"></div>
<div width="338" align="left" colspan="3" height="12"></div>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here in this code, the text box opens in the same page but I want my text box to be displayed in another page (usually in the action page). I am working in a bus website, I want, when an user checks a checkbox (1 or more) to select a seat, I want that no of text boxes to be opened in the next page after the check boxes checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you want. check it and let me know.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Document Title</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<FORM NAME="f1" action="next_page.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkGuar[]" value="mike">&nbsp;Mike<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chkGuar[]" value="joy">&nbsp;Joy<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chkGuar[]" value="harry">&nbsp;harry<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chkGuar[]" value="watson">&nbsp;watson<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chkGuar[]" value="george">&nbsp;george<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chkGuar[]" value="peter">&nbsp;Peter<br />
<input type="submit" name="chksbmt" value="Send" />
<!-- <div id="myrow" style="visibility:hidden">
<input type = text name ='txtGRTNo' tabindex = 19 size="20">
</div>
<div width="338" align="left" colspan="3" height="12"></div> !-->
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

next_page.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['chksbmt'])){
        $counts = count($_POST['chkGuar']);
        echo "this is the next page. you checked $counts checkbox <br /><br />";
        for($i=1;$i<=$counts;$i++){
        echo "<input type='text' style='border:1px solid #000;' value='your text box here'     
     /><br/><br/>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much ..... This is the perfect code i wanted like 4m 10days.. Now my site ll be complete :) again thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is code like your requirement try it

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Document Title</TITLE>

<script type="text/javascript">
function c(){
    alert("Hi");
    this.f1.submit();
}


function test(){
if(document["f1"]["chkGuar"].checked){
document.getElementById("myrow").style.visibility="visible"
}
else{
document.getElementById("myrow").style.visibility="hidden"
}
}

</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<FORM NAME="f1" action="next_page.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkGuar" value="ON" onclick = "c() ; test()">
<!-- <div id="myrow" style="visibility:hidden">
<input type = text name ='txtGRTNo' tabindex = 19 size="20">
</div>
<div width="338" align="left" colspan="3" height="12"></div> !-->
</FORM>



</BODY>
</HTML>
```

next_page.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['chkGuar'])){
    echo "this is the next page. <br />";
    echo "<input type='text' style='border:1px solid #000;' value='your text box here' />";
}
```

Comment: thank u so much .. bt if i want the same process with so many check boxes , means wen a user checks 4 check boxes, it should open 4 text boxes,  with out dat alert box, nly after 'submitting' the check box, the text box should display in the other page. is dat possible ??

Comment: you have to add a submit button for this and after check the multiple check box call that submit button with count of your checked checkbox.

Comment: i ve updated my code n its giving me a textbox after submitting :), i just want this code for multiple textboxes .. just ans me that code.. thank u again ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a second page that get the request.
On the first one, make your for to post to the second path (action and method attributs that are missing in your code).

And then display in the textbox in the second page the content you want from the first one, based on the checkbox checked.

This is the way I see.

Comment: yeah this code displays the text box in the same page, ve nt given ne method or action page, i knw dat.. can u write me the code plz ??

Comment: Sorry but don't have time for thath now I'm at work. Checkout : http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php